# Low Level Protocol for Microservice Orchestration

Tags: rest, redis, network-programming, apache-zookeeper, microservices

Recently I started working with Microservices, I wrote a library for service discovery using Redis to store every service's url and port number, along with a TTL value for the entry. It turned out to be an expensive approach since for every cross service call to any other service required one call to Redis. Caching didn't seem to be a good idea, since the services won't be up all the times, there can be possible downtimes as well.

So I wanted to write a separate microservice which could take care of the orchestration part. For this I need to figure out a really low level network protocol to take care of the exchange of heartbeats(which would help me figure out if any of the service instance goes unavailable). How do applications like zookeeperClient, redisClient take care of heartbeats?

Moreover what is the industry's preferred protocol for cross service calls? 
I have been calling REST Api's over HTTP and eliminated every possibility of Joins across different collections.

Is there a better way to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: completely change tact and use a distributed actor model.

Comment: did I answered your question?

Comment: yes, this helped me clear a lot of things in my head :)

Answer (score 2):

I think the term "Orchestration" is not good for what you are asking. From what I've encountered so far in microservices world the term "Orchestration" is used when a complex business process is involved and not for service discovery. What you need is a [Service registry](http://microservices.io/patterns/service-registry.html) combined with a `Load balancer`. You can find [here](https://www.nginx.com/blog/service-discovery-in-a-microservices-architecture/) all the information you need. Here are some relevant extras that great article:

There are two main service discovery patterns: client‑side discovery and server‑side discovery. Let’s first look at client‑side discovery.

**The Client‑Side Discovery Pattern**

When using client‑side discovery, the client is responsible for determining the network locations of available service instances and load balancing requests across them. The client queries a service registry, which is a database of available service instances. The client then uses a load‑balancing algorithm to select one of the available service instances and makes a request.

[image]

The network location of a service instance is registered with the service registry when it starts up. It is removed from the service registry when the instance terminates. The service instance’s registration is typically refreshed periodically using a heartbeat mechanism.

[Netflix OSS](https://netflix.github.io/) provides a great example of the client‑side discovery pattern. [Netflix Eureka](https://github.com/Netflix/eureka) is a service registry. It provides a REST API for managing service‑instance registration and for querying available instances. [Netflix Ribbon](https://github.com/Netflix/ribbon) is an IPC client that works with Eureka to load balance requests across the available service instances. We will discuss Eureka in more depth later in this article.

The client‑side discovery pattern has a variety of benefits and drawbacks. This pattern is relatively straightforward and, except for the service registry, there are no other moving parts. Also, since the client knows about the available services instances, it can make intelligent, application‑specific load‑balancing decisions such as using hashing consistently. One significant drawback of this pattern is that it couples the client with the service registry. You must implement client‑side service discovery logic for each programming language and framework used by your service clients.

**The Server‑Side Discovery Pattern**

[image]

The client makes a request to a service via a load balancer. The load balancer queries the service registry and routes each request to an available service instance. As with client‑side discovery, service instances are registered and deregistered with the service registry.

The [AWS Elastic Load Balancer](https://aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/) (ELB) is an example of a server-side discovery router. An ELB is commonly used to load balance external traffic from the Internet. However, you can also use an ELB to load balance traffic that is internal to a virtual private cloud (VPC). A client makes requests (HTTP or TCP) via the ELB using its DNS name. The ELB load balances the traffic among a set of registered Elastic Compute Cloud (EC2) instances or EC2 Container Service (ECS) containers. There isn’t a separate service registry. Instead, EC2 instances and ECS containers are registered with the ELB itself.

HTTP servers and load balancers such as [NGINX Plus](https://www.nginx.com/products/) and NGINX can also be used as a server-side discovery load balancer. For example, [this blog](https://www.airpair.com/scalable-architecture-with-docker-consul-and-nginx) post describes using [Consul Template](https://github.com/hashicorp/consul-template) to dynamically reconfigure NGINX reverse proxying. Consul Template is a tool that periodically regenerates arbitrary configuration files from configuration data stored in the [Consul service registry](https://www.consul.io/). It runs an arbitrary shell command whenever the files change. In the example described by the blog post, Consul Template generates an nginx.conf file, which configures the reverse proxying, and then runs a command that tells NGINX to reload the configuration. A more sophisticated implementation could dynamically reconfigure NGINX Plus using either [its HTTP API or DNS](https://www.nginx.com/products/on-the-fly-reconfiguration/).

Some deployment environments such as Kubernetes and Marathon run a proxy on each host in the cluster. The proxy plays the role of a server‑side discovery load balancer. In order to make a request to a service, a client routes the request via the proxy using the host’s IP address and the service’s assigned port. The proxy then transparently forwards the request to an available service instance running somewhere in the cluster.

The server‑side discovery pattern has several benefits and drawbacks. One great benefit of this pattern is that details of discovery are abstracted away from the client. Clients simply make requests to the load balancer. This eliminates the need to implement discovery logic for each programming language and framework used by your service clients. Also, as mentioned above, some deployment environments provide this functionality for free. This pattern also has some drawbacks, however. Unless the load balancer is provided by the deployment environment, it is yet another highly available system component that you need to set up and manage.